# What is the difference between sub-Riemannian and contact geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

What is the difference between [sub-Riemannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Riemannian_manifold) and [contact geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry)? Based on the Wikipédia articles dealing with these topics, they could be special cases of eachother, or even they could be the same.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04374

Comment: This seems to be about math rather than physics, and thus belongs on Math SE.

Comment: Enrico Le Donne's [lecture notes](https://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/5339/sub-Riem_notes.pdf) and youtube videos look pretty good.

Comment: See also:  Hansjörg Geiges, A brief history of contact geometry and topology,
Expositiones Mathematicae, Volume 19, Issue 1, 2001, Pages 25-53,
ISSN 0723-0869, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0723-0869(01)80014-1.
[Science Direct link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086901800141)